# How can I replace a 4-wire manual thermostat with a programmable thermostat?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, baseboard

I"m replacing a 4-wire manual baseboard thermostat with a programmable SBFT2W thermostat. After connecting the wires, there are two lead wires from the old stat that are still unconnected. They are apparently connecting the heater thermo to the heater that will be done by the new stat.  Should these two wires be connected? Any suggestions would be helpful before I blow this unit up.

Comment: What you should have done was noted where the wires connected to the old thermostat and labeled them, then referred to the directions for the new thermostat to determine where they connect.  Can you remember what they connected to before?

Answer (score 1):

Check the wires on the terminal strip in your furnace they should be labeled, match the letters R-R W-W Y-Y G-G from the furnace to the thermostat and usually the colors should match also so: r-red g-green y-yellow and w-white.

Comment: Usually yes but don't trust color, check the other end.